# Wireless with a AR242x / AR542x Atheros wireless adapter doesn't work on an Acer Aspire One ZG8 

Tags: 11.10, wireless, atheros, aspire-one

I'm asking that how to get wlan on?
When I click connections(or something)-button, then I'm trying to get wirless connection on, but it wouldn't go on, so could you help me guys, please?

More information.

lsmod code:

```
Module                  Size  Used by
ppp_deflate            12878  0 
zlib_deflate           26622  1 ppp_deflate
bsd_comp               12842  0 
ppp_async              17307  1 
crc_ccitt              12595  1 ppp_async
parport_pc             32114  0 
ppdev                  12849  0 
joydev                 17393  0 
rfcomm                 38408  0 
bnep                   17923  2 
option                 25463  2 
usb_wwan               19779  1 option
arc4                   12473  2 
snd_hda_codec_realtek   254125  1 
usbserial              37203  7 option,usb_wwan
snd_hda_intel          24262  2 
hso                    33389  0 
snd_hda_codec          91754  2 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_intel
ath5k                 145100  0 
snd_hwdep              13276  1 snd_hda_codec
uvcvideo               67271  0 
videodev               85626  1 uvcvideo
snd_pcm                80435  2 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec
ath                    19387  1 ath5k
mac80211              393459  1 ath5k
btusb                  18160  0 
psmouse                73673  0 
serio_raw              12990  0 
bluetooth             148839  11 bnep,rfcomm,btusb
snd_seq_midi           13132  0 
snd_rawmidi            25241  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq_midi_event     14475  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq                51567  2 snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event
snd_timer              28932  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
snd_seq_device         14172  3 snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq
i915                  505159  3 
cfg80211              172392  3 ath5k,ath,mac80211
snd                    55902  13 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hwdep,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq,snd_timer,snd_seq_device
binfmt_misc            17292  1 
drm_kms_helper         32889  1 i915
drm                   192194  4 i915,drm_kms_helper
soundcore              12600  1 snd
snd_page_alloc         14115  2 snd_hda_intel,snd_pcm
i2c_algo_bit           13199  1 i915
video                  18908  1 i915
lp                     17455  0 
parport                40930  3 parport_pc,ppdev,lp
usb_storage            44173  0 
uas                    17699  0 
ahci                   21634  2 
libahci                25727  1 ahci
atl1e                  32809  0
```

lspci code:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Mobile 945GME Express Memory Controller Hub (rev 03)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 945GME Express Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 03)
00:02.1 Display controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 945GM/GMS/GME, 943/940GML Express Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 03)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 02)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family PCI Express Port 1 (rev 02)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family PCI Express Port 3 (rev 02)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family PCI Express Port 4 (rev 02)
00:1d.0 USB Controller: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB UHCI Controller #1 (rev 02)
00:1d.1 USB Controller: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB UHCI Controller #2 (rev 02)
00:1d.2 USB Controller: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB UHCI Controller #3 (rev 02)
00:1d.3 USB Controller: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB UHCI Controller #4 (rev 02)
00:1d.7 USB Controller: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB2 EHCI Controller (rev 02)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge (rev e2)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 82801GBM (ICH7-M) LPC Interface Bridge (rev 02)
00:1f.1 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 82801G (ICH7 Family) IDE Controller (rev 02)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 82801GBM/GHM (ICH7 Family) SATA AHCI Controller (rev 02)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family SMBus Controller (rev 02)
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Atheros Communications AR8121/AR8113/AR8114 Gigabit or Fast Ethernet (rev b0)
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Atheros Communications Inc. AR242x / AR542x Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) (rev 01)
```

sudo lshw -class network code:

```
*-network               
description: Ethernet interface
product: AR8121/AR8113/AR8114 Gigabit or Fast Ethernet
vendor: Atheros Communications
physical id: 0
bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
logical name: eth0
version: b0
serial: 00:23:8b:a1:e7:2b
capacity: 100Mbit/s
width: 64 bits
clock: 33MHz
capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=ATL1E driverversion=1.0.0.7-NAPI firmware=L1e latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
resources: irq:45 memory:55200000-5523ffff ioport:3000(size=128)
*-network DISABLED
description: Wireless interface
product: AR242x / AR542x Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express)
vendor: Atheros Communications Inc.
physical id: 0
bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
logical name: wlan0
version: 01
serial: 00:24:2b:e3:0f:72
width: 64 bits
clock: 33MHz
capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath5k driverversion=3.0.0-14-generic firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bg
resources: irq:18 memory:54100000-5410ffff
```

lsusb code:

```
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 064e:a102 Suyin Corp. Acer/Lenovo Webcam [CN0316]
Bus 001 Device 026: ID 0af0:7601 Option Globetrotter MO40x 3G Modem (GTM 382)
Bus 001 Device 024: ID 12d1:1506 Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd.
```

sudo rfkill list code:

```
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: yes
8: hso-7: Wireless WAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
```

Is that information enough?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found this solution from the italian ubuntuforums; I translate it to you:

open the file `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` executing the command:

```
sudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

Check if you find:

```
#blacklist acer_wmi
```

and erase the number sign.
If you can't find it, please add at the end:

```
blacklist acer_wmi
```

(obviously without the number sign)

save and reboot.

Then execute:

```
sudo rfkill list
```